# Can I access to the same static method used by another user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, static

I have this static method on C# :

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {

    }

    public static void myOwnMethod(int myValue)
    {
        int internalValue;
        internalValue=myValue+10;
        Console.Write(internalValue);
    }
}
```

now, if user A call MyClass.myOwnMethod(), could user B call the same method called by user A (is static) or when user B call that method  it like to create another "instance" of class/method?

Because could be dangerous have static methods so...

### EXAMPLE

- userA call MyClass.myOwnMethod(10);
- if meanwhile the Console.Write of userA userB call MyClass.myOwnMethod(20), which are the results for each user?

userA get 20 and userB 30 or both get 30?

Comment: Winforms? Webforms? Are the users using the same instance of the program?

Comment: How are users limited? I don't see how users would be prevented from calling your code at all.

Comment: Please explain what 'Users' are in this context.

Comment: added example or what I mean! maybe it's more clear :)

Comment: @Oded : I call these methods from an aspx.cs (web application)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if user A call MyClass.myOwnMethod(), could user B call the same method

Yes, of course.

But what exactly happens depends. Are your 'Users' threads or do they run separate instances of the program?

### After the Update

When you call a static method for 2+ users (requests) in a server application then the inside of that method should be thread-safe. In the example that is the case because

- `internalValue` is a local variable
- `Console.Write()` is thread-safe by design.

But in a 'real' situation you would  be tempted to use share (static) data, and then you would need some form of locking.

Comment: Yeah, but if inside the method I use non-static object, userB should not interact with userA, right? That's what I need...!

Comment: Depends on _how_ you interact with that non-static thingy. Very many possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible. You should avoid using static methods this way. I myself made this mistake with a login class and my collegue took over my user profile.

You can make you classes statics, as long as you yake sure that you dataobjects/classes are not static

Comment: added the target of what I mean! check it out

Answer (score 1):

Static Methods work on the Type and not the instance. So yes, any user could call your Static myOwnMethod().

Answer (score 1):

You haven't mentioned how you are accessing these methods, but the static method will not be duplicated, so both users will call exactly the same code. It is down to the developer to prevent against race conditions that could result from this.

Please read [What Every Dev Must Know About Multithreaded Apps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163744.aspx) on MSDN to understand more about what I mean. I promise you that it is definitely worth reading this article.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean saying user A and user B?

In terms of multithreading: A static method can be called by multiple threads at a time. I think this is what you are talking about.

Ther is no class instance involved when calling a static method.

You have to write the code in your method in a threadsafe manner: Its important that you synchronize the access to global or static data.

Answer (score 1):

For your question： Yes , anyone could call the static method at the same time

For your sample :  in your current case , userA and userB would get the result as their aspect ,

But if your method's parameter is object type , i cannt say so . maybe it is not thread-safe

Comment: I don't understand the last step. Of course if I pass static Object they will edit the same object... but if I pass new object (or I instance new Object into the method) they won't access to the same object. (as the example of int internalValue)...

Answer (score 1):

It totally depends on the scope of your class for user A and user B. if User A and User B are using the static method within a process, yes, they share the method. But if they use the shared class in to different processes, No, the static method would not be shared.